# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I am using the dotnet 3.1 CLI with .NET Core 3.1 on my Mac to learn msbuild and create project files from scratch. I tried the walkthrough on [Microsoft MSBuild documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch?view=vs-2019#use-the-project-file-to-build-the-application), but it failed with this error:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I reference System namespace in my project?

program.cs

```
using System;

class HelloWorld {

    static void Main() {
#if DebugConfig
        Console.WriteLine("WE ARE IN THE DEBUG CONFIGURATION");
#endif

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

project.csproj

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="program.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <Csc Sources="@(Compile)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

CLI:

```
dotnet msbuild project.csproj -t:Build
```

Comment: Could you please share your code? and `csproj` file

Comment: It is exactly as in the link to MS docs in OP.

Comment: This is an outdated document, about old style msbuild projects. You'll need to use new sdk-style projects for dotnet core, here is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-macos)

Comment: I want to create the project.csproj file from scratch without inheriting the default settings from SDK because I want to learn msbuild settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project file looks outdated

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="program.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <Csc Sources="@(Compile)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

For .NET Core development new SDK-style projects are used, something like that

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Follow the [MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-macos) how to build initial solution on Mac OS

Comment: I want to create the project.csproj file from scratch without inheriting the default settings from SDK because I want to learn msbuild settings.

Comment: You can use only sdk-style projects on mac os with .NET core. You can use most msbuild settings as usual